# Java telnet server

Tags: java, telnet, embedded-server

Does anyone know of a simple telnet server?

I want to embed in my application and set my own commands
something simple not complex .

Answer (score 7):

Try this one,

http://code.google.com/p/telnetd-x/

A telnetd alone is useless. You have to connect it to a shell. We use jacl and jyson as shell.

Comment: ok question about telnetd
what should i do in cases 
when i can send many commands and get response 
without closing the connection immediately 
like all of the examples in telnetd shows

Answer (score 4):

I have written a simple Telnet server in Java: [TelnetStdioRedirector](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/TelnetStdioRedirector/)

Answer (score 1):

I did as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "hostname";
    int port = 8080;
    try (Socket pingSocket = new Socket(url, port)) {
      try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(pingSocket.getOutputStream(), true); BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pingSocket.getInputStream()));) {
        out.println("ping");
        System.out.println("Telnet Success: " + in.readLine());
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Telnet Fail: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```